Windows 11 calendar widget with Google integration
I'd like a calendar widget that permanently displays on the desktop. I don't just want a calendar app, I want it to always display on the desktop - like the Windows 7 widgets - so that I don't have to click any buttons to open the calendar. Also, I don't just want a tiny calendar with the numbers in a square, I want a weekly view that shows my tasks/events (like the Google Calendar weekly view).
When I search for this, I can only find calendars that just have a program which you have to open first, but no widget, and not all of them even support Google Calendar.
I've found Rainlendar, which has a Google Calendar integration on the paid version (10EUR), but I can't find pictures of the widget on the desktop, so I don't know if that's truly what I want.
Basically I just want to have my Google Calendar, but permanently on the desktop instead of in a browser tab, so I can instantly see my tasks.

Write to the author to provide you screenshots. If you need them for Google specifically, although I doubt that widget differs much from the free version without Google integrated, which you can test and see the looks. You won't find anything better.

The only thing I have found, that is still available is the Windows Calendar app itself.  It supports syncing with Google Calendar.  While it an app, not a widget, you can autostart it.

I did check that app, but apparently it's being replaced by New Outlook. I didn't think about how I can autostart programs though.
